# Let $a,b>0$ and $a+b\leqslant 2$. Prove that $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b} +\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{a} \leqslant 2.$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $\displaystyle a,b>0$ and $\displaystyle a+b\leqslant 2$. Prove that $$\displaystyle \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b} +\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{a} \leqslant 2.$$
（reduce fractions is not a smart idea I think)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: It is interesting. You may edit your question including some information (e.g. source, attempt). Perhaps someone will vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

$(\frac{a}{b})^b+(\frac{b}{a})^a=e^{b\ln(\frac{a}{b})}+e^{a\ln(\frac{b}{a})}$. Let $x=\ln(\frac{a}{b})$, then $e^{bx}+e^{-ax}=\frac{e^{(a+b)x}+1}{e^{ax}}<\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{ax}}$ Since $a>0$ , $b>0$ and $a+b<2$, we have $a<2$. From that we deduce, $(2-a)x<0$ and then $e^{(2-a)x}<1$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Typo：$x=ln(\frac{a}{b})$